# how can i update the name and color of a task by providing task id within text box using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

```
 Array
    (
        [_id] => ed94bf70c9105
        [name] => example
        [description] => 
        [color] => yellow
        [columnId] => 258f22019487
        [totalSecondsSpent] => 0
        [totalSecondsEstimate] => 0
    )
```

from the above array how can i update the name and color of a task by providing task id within text box.

Comment: who told that this is an array..?!?

Comment: Please elaborate your need.

Comment: That's not JavaScript.  It's an interesting syntax, but it's not JavaScript.

Comment: the above code is the output of some url.what actually i am trying to do is by providing id "ed94bf70c9105" into a textbox i want to update the name and color fields of the array on particular url.

Answer (score 0):

```
var tasks = [
    {
        _id : "ed94bf70c9105",
        name : "example",
        description : "" ,
        color : "yellow",
        columnId : "258f22019487",
        totalSecondsSpent : 0,
        totalSecondsEstimate : 0
    }
];
```

Here's JavaScript.

As far as changing the color and name, you first need to create some sort of page element with that information in it.  If you just want to change the datum itself, then $("#myInputBoxId").val() gives you the ID, and all you have to do is walk the array until you find the ID and change the color field of that item.

Comment: How to read json data and populate html table on button click?

Comment: below is the array of json and i want to only display the name,description and checkbox into html table using jquery.

Comment: Array
(
    [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [columnId] => 258f2200948
            [columnName] => aaaa
            [tasksLimited] => 
            [tasks] => Array
                (
                    [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [_id] => 5f4d17eeff
                            [name] => test
                            [description] => 
                            [color] => yellow
                         )

Comment: please help me in doing the above task

Comment: I don't know what the table looks like.  It's possible to create DOM content with jQuery, but I don't think that's the usual way of going about things.  So, I don't know what the page looks like, and for some reason I'm getting the impression that I might be doing your homework for you.

Comment: It's not something I use jQuery for (initially creating content).  Here's creating the content from the table: http://jsfiddle.net/8hwzU/

Comment: My guess is that if you don't know how to go from that to modifying the content in jQuery it's because you *don't know jQuery.*  This forum is too small to teach you jQuery--so check out the documentation on the jQuery site or buy/borrow a book on it.  There's a lot going on that can't be explained in a couple of answers on StackOverflow.